# Integral Simplified Answer Clarification

Tags: calculus

I solved the following integral as follows -
$$
\int \frac{2 x^{2}}{1-6 x^{3}} d x
$$

$$
2 \int \frac{x^{2}}{u} \cdot \frac{d u}{-18 x^{2}}
$$

$$
\frac{-2}{18} \int \frac{1}{u} \cdot d u
$$

$$
\frac{-1}{9} \ln \left|1-6 x^{3}\right|+c
$$

But when I check the answer online in the integral-calculator, their result is:
$$
\frac{-1}{9} \ln \left|6 x^{3}-1\right|+c
$$

So my question is why is that the better answer?

Thanks.

Comment: $|a|=|-a|$ can be used

Comment: Those expressions are the same. The absolute value of a difference can be written with either one first. Try |5-4| and |4-5|. What do you notice?

Comment: Thanks - got it.  When I had checked my answer in the integral calculator - it went from my expression to the last one using the following statement (and that's the part which I didn't understand.  "...The problem is solved. Apply the absolute value function to arguments of logarithm functions in order to extend the antiderivative's domain".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer lies in your question

- **Your steps:**

$$-\frac1{9}\int\frac1{u}du = -\frac1{9}\ln\left|1-6x^3\right|+C$$
So, here you took absolute of $1-6x^3$  however, you could have write $-\frac1{9}\ln(1-6x^3)$

We know,  ​$$\color{blue}{\int \frac{f'}{f} = \ln(f)}$$

Now, let's take two cases

- **case $1$:**
  $$\begin{align*} 
  \int\frac{2x^2}{1-6x^3}dx
  & = -\frac 1{9}\int\frac{-18x^2}{1-6x^3}\\
  &= -\frac1{9}\ln(1-6x^3)+C\\
  \end{align*}$$
- **case $2$:**
  $$\begin{align*} 
  \int\frac{2x^2}{1-6x^3}dx
  & = -\frac 1{9}\int\frac{18x^2}{6x^3-1}\\
  &= -\frac1{9}\ln(6x^3-1)+C\\
  \end{align*}$$

So, We can write

$$\color{blue}{\int \frac{f'}{f} = \ln|f|}$$

Otherwise, also you can take derivates of both answers and check they'll be the same. As, $|x|=|-x|$